# How to undo-redo features like zoom in, zoom out using Command pattern in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I have a QGraphicsView, which contains rectangle, polyline, text etc. I also have some features to transform the view like zoom in, zoom out, Fit in view, change the color on mouse right click etc. I want to add few more features like Undo and Redo.

> Undo means, user should cancel the effect of last command executed and
> show previous transformation. So If user did transformation like zoom
> in -> zoom in -> fit in -> zoom in and now pressed Undo then view's
> fit in position should get displayed.

I have tried `Command pattern` to implement Undo-Redo feature. But I did it to add/remove rectangle,polyline in design. And it worked.
HCommand.h

```
#include <QUndoCommand>
#include<QGraphicsItem>
#include<QGraphicsScene>

class myCommand : public QUndoCommand
{

public:
        HCommand(QGraphicsItem* mItem, QGraphicsScene* scene);
        HCommand(QGraphicsScene* scene, QGraphicsView* mView);// for fitIn

 private:
        QGraphicsItem* mItem;
        QGraphicsScene* mScene;
        QGraphicsView* mView;

        void undo();
        void redo();
};
```

HCommand.cpp

```
#include "hcommand.h"

HCommand::HCommand(QGraphicsItem* item, QGraphicsScene* scene):
   mItem(item), mScene(scene)

{}

void HCommand::undo()
{
    if(mItem)
        mScene->removeItem(mItem);
}

void HCommand::redo()
{
    if(mItem)
        mScene->addItem(mItem);
}
```

Widget.h

```
class Widget : public QGraphicsView
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~Widget();

    Rectangle r;
    PolyLine p;
    QUndoStack* undoStack;
    void undo();
    void redo();
private:
    Ui::Widget *ui;
    QGraphicsScene* scene;
    QGraphicsView* view;
}
```

Widget.cpp

```
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QGraphicsView(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::Widget)
{     
    ui->setupUi(this);
    scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    view = new QGraphicsView(this);    
    view->setScene(scene);
    undoStack = new QUndoStack(this);
    ui->verticalLayout_2->addWidget(view);       
}          
void Widget::undo()
{
    undoStack->undo();
}

void Widget::redo()
{
    undoStack->redo();
}       
void Widget::on_schematicBtn_clicked()
{
    QGraphicsRectItem* in = r.createRect(20,160,20,20);
    scene->addItem(in);
    HCommand* com = new HCommand(in,scene);
    undoStack->push(com);        
    // many rectangles and polyline code, same as above     
}
```

But now I want to do Undo-Redo for Zoom In , Zoom Out, Fit In. But whenever I zoom in/out, I zoomed in/out `full view`

```
void Widget::on_zoomIn_clicked()
{
    double sFactor = 1.2;
    view->scale(sFactor,sFactor);
}


void Widget::on_zoomOut_clicked()
{
    double sFactor = 1.2;
    view->scale(1/sFactor,1/sFactor);
}         
 
void Widget::on_fitInBtn_clicked()
{
    view->resetTransform();
}
```

So the question is :

> In above code I am pushing particular rectangle in stack so for zoom
> in/out how to push full view in stack ? So that, later I can pull it
> out from stack ? Or this can be implemented differently ?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: First you do not need to add the item before pushing the command. The redo function will be called on push. And I do not unterstand your question, you can easily write a class which has an undo to zoom in and a redo to zoom out.

Comment: @gerum : Sorry but I am not understanding what to push in the stack while undo and redo   ?  I am zooming in whole view not any single item. Can you help me in understanding ?

Comment: As a side note:  operations like "zoom in" and "zoom out" don't typically change the state of the data that the user is interacting with; rather they only change the state of the viewport that the user is using to view the data.  Given that, are you sure you *want* to put those operations onto the undo/redo stack?  I would find it surprising that an "undo" operation un-did a zoom, just as I would find it surprising if an "undo" operation un-did my scrolling of a scroll-bar.

Comment: @tushar Ask yourself what do you push to the stack to add an item, an custom class implementing thr QUndoCommand interface. So if you want to redo/undo a zoom,you should write a new class where the implementation of the redo function zoom in or out. I want to add that this answer is pure technical and I would also not recommend to use the unfo stack for something like zooming.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Yes, I am sure. I want to put those operations on stack.  Even I want to store history what user did with design so it will be useful  for debugging purpose. I am not sure, how to maintain history may be last 10 activities user has performed. (currently we only have zoom in/out/fit in feature. Later on we are going to add more feature ) But I want it.  So can you tell me how to do it ?

Comment: @tushar I imagine you'd need to create a subclass of `QUndoCommand` and override the `undo()` and `redo()` methods to call `view->scale(x)` with the appropriate value of `x`.... and push that object onto the undo-stack whenever the user clicks a zoom-in or zoom-out button.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Your suggestion worked for Zoom in/out. But I could not use it for Fit In. I have updated Fit in code in question.  And I tried this way.  `void Widget::on_fitInBtn_clicked()
{
    view->resetTransform();
    ICommand* command3 = new ICommand(scene,view);
    undoStack->push(command3);
}`

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I know above way is wrong but how to correct it ? Can you help me ?

Comment: @tushar since your fit-in action overwrites the view’s transform with a default one, executing it destroys the information of what the transform was before the fit-in was executed.  That means that in order to undo it later you’d need to store the view’s current transform as a member-variable in your QUndoCommand object, before resetting the view.  Then you can undo() it by restoring the saved transform.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Sorry but this time I did not get you properly.  I tried this way : `void Widget::on_fitInBtn_clicked()
{
    QGraphicsView* mView = view;
    ICommand* command3 = new ICommand(scene,mView);
    undoStack->push(command3);
    view->resetTransform();
}`

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I am getting blank screen after pressing `Undo` button. Can you correct me ? I have updated `ICommand` constructor for `fitIn`.

Comment: @tushar I won't debug your program for you, but if you'd like some guidance on how to debug it for yourself, I find this article to be helpful:  https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Sorry but I did not want to say debug for me. I just want to confirm, whether the changes I have done are correct or not ?  Is my approach in `on_fitInBtn_clicked()` is correct ? ( in my previous comment, I have posted a code )

Comment: @tushar I dont see anything in the code in the comment that would save the view's current transform into `command3`; how will your `undo()` method know what to restore the transform to if you never saved it?